# Como escribir un texto al lado de un icono en Flutter

Tags: flutter

El problema que me surge es que él widget esta dentro de un `Container` `Column` y al querer crear otro `Container` para poner el texto me lo pone debajo del icono y no al lado.

No conozco ninguna propiedad que pueda utilizar, para poder escribir al lado, e probado bastantes cosas, pero no consigo el resultado deseado.

Gracias, un saludo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Widget renderTexto(){

    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 190,
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color:Colors.white,
        border: Border(
        top: BorderSide(   
      color: Colors.black12,
      width: 1,
          ),
        bottom: BorderSide(   
      color: Colors.black12,
      width: 1,
          ),
        ),
      ),
     child: Column(
        children: [Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 10,
            left: 17,
            bottom: 1
          ),
          child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          child: Text( 'Post title',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black ,
              fontSize:20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w800
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ),
        Container( 
        child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Text(
                'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
            Row(
              children: [
                Icon(
                  Icons.location_on,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Barcelona',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                )
              ],
            ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
     )
     )//aki e marca fallo
    );
  }
```

Comment: Sería bueno que agregues una imagen de como se ve actualmente y como deseas mostrarlo para tener más info

Comment: si la verdad es que podria haber puesta imagen

Comment: ufff me explique fatal diego, e colgado una foto de como quiero que se bea , aunque estoy probando cosas con tu ejemplo haber si me sale. Gracias diego.

Comment: ahí actualicé la respuesta

Comment: ya lo pille jeje pero me marca un fallo de indentacion abajo

Comment: aquí corre todo bien

Comment: cabie el codigo entero de mi pregunta , te funciona correctamente añadiendo el contenedor del Post title ?

Comment: ya esta diego un cierre que no lo habia puesta muchisimas gracias voy a estudiar lo de los layouts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes usar `Row` para alinear elementos en horizontal, el `Column` agrega elementos y los posiciona en vertical, y no te olvides de usar `Expanded` para decirle que ocupe el espacio disponible, aquí tienes tu ejemplo corregido:

```dart
 Widget renderTexto() {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 190,
      //color:Colors.white,
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        border: Border(
          top: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.black12,
            width: 1,
          ),
          bottom: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.black12,
            width: 1,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(children: [
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 17, bottom: 1),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Text(
              'Post title',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 4, left: 17, right: 6, bottom: 2),
                  child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      child: Text(
                          'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper.',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.grey[400],
                              fontSize: 19,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300))),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 4,
                  left: 17,
                ),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Image.asset('assets/images/icons/ic_location.png',
                      width: 25),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
```

Te recomiendo este enlace para que aprendas un poco más sobre layouts en Flutter: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout

**UPDATE**

Según la imagen que adjuntaste, el código podría quedar así :

```dart
  Widget renderTexto() {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        border: Border(
          top: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.black12,
            width: 1,
          ),
          bottom: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.black12,
            width: 1,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Text(
                'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
            Row(
              children: [
                Icon(
                  Icons.location_on,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Barcelona',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: gracias diego me lo mirare.